# Google Drive picker no carga

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive

El día de ayer se encontraron intermitencias con el API de Drive Picker, encontré un post que sugeria cambiar el path del script pero ambos no funcionan, al querer invocar el picker este no carga

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

<--------------Código completo----------------->

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    };
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    function Load() {
        gapi.load('picker', {
            'callback': function() {
                pickerApiLoaded = true;
            }
        });
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
            .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {

        if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {


             var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent("0B2_PIECATjTWZFlrQUxTQkpUR3M"))
                .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)         
                .setOAuthToken(token)
                .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
                .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                .setSize(566,350)
                .build();

            picker.setVisible(true);

        } else {
            showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
        }
    }
```

Alguien sabe si este problema es general en Google o existe algún reporte de falla?

Al inspeccionar la consola muestra el siguiente mensaje de error

VM3331 userCodeAppPanel:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of undefined
    at createPicker (VM3331 userCodeAppPanel:35)
    at Me (2483804561-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__es.js:52)
    at 2483804561-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__es.js:6
    at cg.J (2483804561-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__es.js:84)
    at nd (2483804561-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__es.js:27)
    at id (2483804561-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__es.js:28)
    at 2483804561-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__es.js:25

Comment: Alfredo, por favor abre la consola de tu navegador "presiona la tecla F12 y selecciona la pestaña Console" y ejecuta de nuevo tu código. revisa si hay errores. Si tienes errores, copia y pega los errores al [edit] tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

El ejemplo en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs funciona sin problemas. Comparando el código del ejemplo con el de la pregunta, el de la pregunta se observa incompleto.

## Código

Del enlace citado arriba, específica del ejemplo en la sección File-open dialogs se tomó el siguiente código, el cual fue probado hace uno momentos, siguiendo las indicaciones de la página en cuestión.

### Código.gs

```
/**
 * Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
 */
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
      .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Picker.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

/**
 * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
 * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
 * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
 * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
 * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
 * in the user's Drive.
 *
 * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
 */
function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

### Picker.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'ABC123 ... ';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token from the server-side script so that
     * it can be passed to Picker. This technique keeps Picker from needing to
     * show its own authorization dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope
     * that Picker needs is available in Apps Script. Otherwise, your Picker code
     * will need to declare its own OAuth scopes.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Picker that can access the user's spreadsheets. This function
     * uses advanced options to hide the Picker's left navigation panel and
     * default title bar.
     *
     * @param {string} token An OAuth 2.0 access token that lets Picker access the
     *     file type specified in the addView call.
     */
    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
            // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays an error message within the #result element.
     *
     * @param {string} message The error message to display.
     */
    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Rubén, en esta sentencia `var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Picker.html')` el archivo `Picker.html` dónde debe estar alojado? en el drive donde esté el archivo asociado al código `.gs`, en local, o dónde? porque a mi me arroja un error que dice que no encuentra el html.. he probado con rutas absolutas al drive, en local, le he puesto el .html, sin el .html, y no doy con la tecla.
Si pudieras guiarme.. gracias!!

Comment: @Borjinha10: El editor de secuencia de comando maneja tres formatos de archivo, .gs, .html y .json, los primeros dos se crean desde el menú Archivo, el último es usado exclusivamente para el manifiesto, el cual se crea de forma automática. Si requieres mayor orientación, por favor, publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto que me has dicho, ya me has orientado, el `.html` debe estar alojado en el mismo lugar que el archivo `.gs`. Te lo agradezco.