# Indicar las URL en una celda activa en lugar de hacerlo por filas, utilizando Google Picker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Encontré una parte de lo que pedia inicialmente (edito mi consulta). Estoy utilizando el código de presta esta página https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cCFleHUZaC0cC38ojPe4GaZ03oER8ku_WX9RAaXdAeg/copy, donde obtengo las urls de los archivos y carpetas seleccionados desde Google Picker y las coloca una por una en cada fila de mi hoja de cálculo (tantas como haya seleccionado).

Estoy intentando modificar el código para que en lugar de indicar las urls por filas lo haga en una única celda (por ejemplo la activa). Pero no lo consigo, los valores resultantes siempre son nulos. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Mil gracias

La función que indica las urls en las filas de la hoja de cáclculo es esta:

```
function loadDocInfo(data){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
ws.clear();
ws.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
//ws.getActiveCell().setValue(data[1][2]);
}
```

Relacionada con esta función del codigo html:

```
`function pickerCallback(data) {
 var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
 if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
 var docInfo = [["Title", "ID", "URL"]];   
 var docs = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
 for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i ++){
 var doc = docs[i];
 var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
 var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
 var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
 docInfo.push([title, id, url]);
  }
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
   google.script.host.close();
    }).loadDocInfo(docInfo);
    
  } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
    google.script.host.close();
  }}
```

Comment: Sí es posible. Ahora inténtalo y si tienes una problema concreto abres una pregunta mostrando el código, los errores que tienes, etc.

Comment: Debes mostrar el código de lo que has intentado y especialmente en donde tienes problemas, de lo contrario es complicado que se te brinde ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Encontré una manera de listar archivos tipo hoja de calculo desde G drive en google sheets. Pero no es lo que necesito. Lo que necesito es que el código abra una dialogo para que busque en cualquier carpeta de drive y en mi pc el archivo o los archivos deseados y al aceptar se indiquen las urls en la celda activa.

Comment: este es el código que encontré . Gracias                                                                                   . function ListarHCGoogle(){

  var hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("nombre hoja activa");

  var cabecera = hoja.getRange("A1:A1");

  var Datoscabecera = cabecera.setValues([["Url-folder"]]);

  var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById('id carpeta');

  var docs = carpeta.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

    while (docs.hasNext()) {

     var doc = docs.next();

     hoja.appendRow([doc.getParents().next().getUrl()])

    }

}

Comment: Hola, encontré esta página para buscar archivos desde una hoja de cálculo, pero solo se redirige a los folders, no a los archivos https://www.labnol.org/code/20039-google-picker-with-apps-script. Siguiendo el hilo de mi consulta,¿ cómo podría modificar el código para poder elegir no solo carpetas sino tambien archivos y que los archivos elegidos se indicaran en la celda seleccionada y activa? Gracias por vuestra ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: En lugar de agregar la aclaración como un "pegote" es mejor que revises la redacción completa y sobre todo actualizar el titulo que este sintetice de forma apropiada lo que estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias @Rubén por guiarme. Siento las molestias. Acabo de editar mi consulta.

Comment: El código está incompleto. Te sugiero revisar mi respuesta a https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/61402/65 (no me acordaba haberla publicado aquí)

Comment: Hola, el código utilizado está en ejemplo del enlace que adjunté en el comentario. Lo que hace es añadir tantas url´s por fila como archivos haya seleccionado en el G. Picker. Funciona correctamente salvo que deseo que todas las url´s de los archivos seleccionados aparezcan juntas, en una misma celda y separada cada una por comas. Entiendo que debo modificar la instrucción ws.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data); pero no sé cómo hacerlo .La respuesta de [es.stackoverflow.com/q/61402/65] no es lo mismo que pregunto, aunque parecidos, la versión que adjunto está ampliada

Answer (score 0):

En una celda de una hoja de cálculo de Google sólo se pueden insertar números, texto, formulas e imágenes. Si los documentos cuentan con URL puedes agregar el URL pero no el archivo.

Los métodos más comunes son `setValue`, `setValues` y `appendRow` para agregar los URLs. Los primeros son métodos de Class Range y el segundo es de Class Sheet.

Lo primero es obtener los URLs. Si los archivos están alojados en Google Drive tu eres su propietario o están compartidos contigo puedes usar el servicio `DriveApp` o el servicio avanzado de Google Drive para obtener los URLs. Cabe destacar que hay varios URLs.

Comment: Disculpa, me referia a urls. Lo he explicado mal

Comment: @SalvaSolbes Actualicé mi respuesta. De todas formas te sugiero editar tu pregunta para que la hagas más clara, muestres lo que has intentado e incluyas una breve descripción de lo que has buscado. Nota: Los comentarios deben limitarse a hablar del contenido sobre una pregunta / respuesta responder a un comentario pero considera los comentarios como elementos temporales, por lo que todo lo que sea relevante para entender una pregunta, respuesta debe en incluirse en la misma.